# Google Assistant can't register my device

Tags: assistant

I register on GA my project, receive and save client_secret.json and create credentials.json
Complete all steps of register device: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device

and try to test on googlesamples-assistant-hotword:

googlesamples-assistant-hotword --device-model-id 'bridge-xxxxxx-bridge-igzdf5'
device_model_id: bridge-xxxxxx-bridge-igzdf5
device_id: 0CE81A09B69F736CBC03F8C93F659C55

```
This device is not registered. This means you will not be able to use
Device Actions or see your device in Assistant Settings. In order to
register this device follow instructions at:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device
```

ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {"is_muted": false}
ON_START_FINISHED

what's may by wrong ?